# сумма квадратов от 12 до 88

Tags: c++, математика

Помогите с реализацией этого задания в стиле ооп. 3мя циклами. Я попробовал сделать через for но без ооп

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double N, sum = 0, stepen;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    cout << "Введите число N" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i = 12; i <= N; i++)
    {
        stepen = i*i;
        sum = sum + stepen;
    }
    cout << "Результат = " << sum << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sum[i=a..b](i*i) = (b*(b+1)*(2*b+1)-a*(a-1)*(2*a-1))/6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так сойдет? :)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<int T>
struct Square
{
    static const int value = T*T;
};

template<int B, int E>
struct Sum
{
    static const int value = Square<B>::value + Sum<B+1,E>::value;
};

template<int B>
struct Sum<B,B>
{
    static const int value = Square<B>::value;
};

int main()
{
    cout << Sum<12,88>::value << endl;
}
```

Ну, раз обязательно нужны классы...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Square
{
public:
    Square(int x):value(x){}
    int val() const
    {
        if (value < 0) throw "Wrong data!";
        int p = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < value; ++i)
            p += value;
        return p;
    }
private:
    int value;
};

class Sum
{
public:
    Sum(int b, int e):b(b),e(e){}
    int val() const
    {
        if (b >= e) throw "Wrong data!";
        return sums(e) - sums(b-1);
    }
private:
    static int sums(int n)
    {
        int s = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
            s += Square(i).val();
        return s;
    }
    int b, e;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int N;
        cin >> N;
        cout << Sum(12,N).val() << endl;
    } catch(const char * e)
    {
        cerr << e << endl;
    }
}
```

И циклов побольше :)

Comment: замените структуру на класс :D по заданию надо же

Comment: неплохой вариант, сойдет конечно

Comment: @pavel Только для вас :) - см. обновленный ответ...

Comment: @Harry почему 1 вариант мне кажется более читаемым...

Comment: @pavel Вам таки надо ехать или достаточно шашечек для преподавателя? :) Я даже возведение в квадрат циклом организовал! :)

Comment: @Harry большое спасибо, подходит

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите это сделать максимально коротко и быстро, я бы посоветовал делать так

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::cout << N*(N+1)*(2*N+1)/6 - 506;
    return 0;
}
```

У вас используется `double` где лучше использовать целочисленный тип. Ну и цикл тут вообще не нужен.

Comment: в задании 3 цикла. желательно хоть 2 реализовать + обязательно юзать классы